# Logging in dotnet-core console-apps and class libraries?

Tags: .net, logging, console-application, log4net, .net-core

**log4net:**

- Is there native a support from log4net?
- As there is no project config, where would the log4net appenders go?
- Is it better to configure log4net in code?

**Microsoft.Extensions.Logging**

- Is the built in logging better option and should be implemented?

**Any other candidates?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, the introduction of the **Microsoft.Extensions.Logging** needs some clarification, I recommend reading this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx which states:

> Logging? Why on earth do we need a new logging framework? We already have NLog, Log4Net, Loggr, Serilog and the built-in Microsoft.Diagnostics.Trace/Debug/TraceSource, just to name a few.

...

> Therefore, you’re probably tempted to write your own logging API wrapper that invokes whichever particular logging framework you or your company chooses this week.

...

> What Microsoft is providing with Microsoft.Extensions.Logging is that wrapper so everyone doesn’t have to write their own.

Now, there are some out-of-the box sinks that Microsoft shipped, they are listened here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#built-in-logging-providers

As you can see a lot of destinations are not there, like logging to a file.

Luckily for you and me there are already some .Net logging implementations that adopt the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging interfaces like ILogger. Some are listened here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging#third-party-logging-providers

If you are willing to bet on another logging framework I personally would recommend a logging framework that provides structured logging like Serilog (https://serilog.net/), which has out-of-the-box support for the new .Net Core logging interfaces.

Also, read this for the advantages of structured logging: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/312197/benefits-of-structured-logging-vs-basic-logging

**EDIT:** There is native support for .Net Core for log4net using this NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RobertHargreaves.log4net.Trunk/
To configure it using the config file see this blogpost: https://stackify.com/making-log4net-net-core-work/

It does not seems to have native support for the Ilogger and ILoggerFactory interfaces of the Microsoft.Extensions.Logging system.

Comment: Thanks @Peter. This is very useful and insightful. I ended up using NLog https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging which has quite a few appenders built in, so fits the purpose very well.